# installing an extension using vqmod

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, vqmod

I recently installed VQmod for opencart and I've tried to add my first vQmod xml file.
The VQmod installation was successful and I see the message

```
VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!
```

when I visit the `/vqmod/install/` URL as expected

The extension I tried to install can be found [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11428)

I added the xml file to the root folder of my site and the `/vqmod/xml/` folder but I don't see a change. No new module appears in the modules page and I don't see the extension working as expected. I also don't get any error messages

Comment: One question: in the extension's description it is said: "`click on the field You want to edit`" - did You do that or You just do not see the input fields anywhere and thus got confused? I guess the extension works the same way as new versions of `phpMyAdmin` - after clicking on the field You can edit it and after clicking out of it is automatically saved by AJAX call...

Comment: To check that I am not mistaking on what the functionality is, I "installed" the extension by following step by step the changes instructed in the extension xml and the extension now works. So it's something with the vqmod not working :(

Comment: If the extension **now works** then there is nothing wrong with the vQmod as it is actually working. Or not?

Comment: No you didn't understand me. The vqmod doesn't work. The vqmod xml describes changes to the php code that should be migrated automatically in runtime, I made the changes manually and staticaly and only that way it works

Comment: If You made the changes manually then the vQmod extension probably won't work anymore as it may not find concrete places to replace (as You may have already replaced them). Try to undo the changes, load the vQmod extension again and check the files in `/vqmod/vqcache/` - the files that are modified by the extension should be here - open them and check the appropriate places whether the changes were performed. vQmod cannot be working improperly as it is used by thousands of people for few years now and You are the first to happen it might not work... Really strange... Contact the extension dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file needs to be in the `/vqmod/xml/` folder as you've rightly done (the root of the folder one can be deleted as it's not required). As for the mod not showing up, vQmods don't add modules to anywhere - they virtually edit files in certain spots. From the looks of the extension you need to go to `CATALOG > PRODUCTS` in your admin and then you will notice you can edit products there. A few of things to check

- You are using the correct version for your OpenCart install and that it is compatible

  - If you don't, you'll need to get that version instead
- You have files in `/vqmod/vqcache/` and that if you delete them and refresh your OpenCart store, the files regenerate

  - If they don't, check the permissions on the directory and that you have the OpenCart version of vQmod, including the `/vqmod/xml/vqmod_opencart.xml` file
- You have no errors from the mod (see `/vqmod/logs/` followed by the day name such as Tue.log)

  - If you do, contact the developer to get a fix if they can. Remember that while vQmods can work well together, that depends largely on the competence of the developer to make it as dynamic as possible. Conflicts can always occur however

Comment: That's exactly the problem - the products aren't editable from the catalog>products. All was checked - I have the opencart and not the standalone. I have opencart 1.5.5.1 with vqmod 2.3.2 , there are 6 files in the cache and after deleting store refresh bring them back. And the /vqmod/logs/ is empty... Thank you but still nothing works

Comment: With files regenerating and no log file errors, it suggests that the mod is working exactly as it should. One final option would be to try deleting the `/vqmod/mods.cache` file in case that is using a stale version of mods

Comment: @JayGilford I am trying to install this bulk discount extension and error log says REQUEST URI : /Cell-Phone-Accessories?product_id=604
VQMod::_parseMods - DOM UNABLE TO LOAD: /home/mobibi5/public_html/vqmod/xml/_discounts.xml
Any thoughts how to get rid of this error? When I open the discount extension under catalogue->discounts it just shows a blank page, also product detail page on store is also blank.

Comment: @Faizan If it's unable to parse it, then it's being ignored. Ensure you upload a copy of the xml using binary mode with your ftp client as it appears to be corrupted

Answer (score 0):

1. download the VQMOD from this link https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/downloads/list
2. upload the ZIP file (case of server)
3. extract the ZIP file and past root folder directory (in case of localhost)
   exp (site folder name is shop (shoo/vqmod))
4. run on url  (http:/open/vqmod/install/)
5. exit